# Espresso AccessibilityChecks Testing Deprecated

Tags: android, testing, gradle, accessibility, android-espresso

I am automating accessibility testing with espresso, but it reports that [`androidx.test.espresso.contrib.AccessibilityChecks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/contrib/AccessibilityChecks) as deprecated.

I surfed the internet and found the non-deprecated [`AccessibilityChecks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/accessibility/AccessibilityChecks.html) class which should be used instead. But would be appreciate if anyone can provide the non-deprecated gradle dependency

**This is my testing class**

```
import androidx.test.espresso.contrib.AccessibilityChecks;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class AccessibilityChecksTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void turnOnAccessibility() {
        AccessibilityChecks.enable();
    }

}
```

**Dependency**

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below is the right dependency for the non-deprecated [`AccessibilityChecks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/accessibility/AccessibilityChecks.html) I found it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project#android-test-dependencies) along with many other `Espresso` testing APIs

```
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.2.0'
```